# How to indicate a point at which Emmet code is supposed to start?

Tags: code-snippets, emmet

Typically an Emmet command starts at a line or after a space, like `h1>{Header}` or like `text sup>{super}`.  However, I am writing something like `x<sup>2</sup>` or `x<sub>2</sub>` over and over again, and can't obviously use an Emmet command to do this with a small number of keystrokes.  If I write `xsup>{2}` and tab, obviously that's not going to work.  I can write `x sup>{2}` and tab, but then I have to go back and erase my space.

Now I know I could do something like this:

```
{x}+(sup>{2})
```

But the problem with THIS solution is that, in fact, I'm often writing much longer lines of mathematical expressions involving many instances of super- and sub-scripts.  In fact, pretty often I write super-scripts that have their own sub-scripts.  When I pursue this sort of solution, I really have to plan out my entire Emmet command before I start writing it, and then if I made a mistake it is not easy to go back and edit.  It's much better if I can write these in small increments that can be fixed in equally small and local ways, as is usually the flow when writing in Emmet.

So what I was hoping for, if it exists, is some sort of "start" symbol for Emmet commands other than space.  For instance, if `$` were such a symbol, then `x$sup>{2}` would do the job.  If such a symbol existed, it would mark the start of Emmet code and get auto-removed after tabbing.

Alternately if that doesn't exist, it would be great if there were some command you could give to delete the white space after tabbing.  So for instance, it could be `x sup>{2}$` where tabbing after the `$` instructs Emmet to remove the white space which precedes the Emmet command.

Does any such solution exist in Emmet?

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text, you can run Enter Abbreviation Mode command: it will capture anything you type as abbreviation, validate it and show interactive preview. Then simply `Tab` or `Enter` to expand it or `Esc` to reset.

See more at https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin#disable-abbreviation-capturing